# How to prevent SKShapeNode handled with touch position from going beyond a circle path?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm using SpriteKit for iOS app with Swift.

I made a small SKShapeNode("ball") and a big circle path("room"), and I want a SKShapeNode to stay within the circle.

Here is my code:

```swift
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var isFingerOnBall = false

    var ball: SKShapeNode!
    var room: SKShapeNode!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

        if let body = physicsWorld.body(at: touchLocation) {
            if body.node!.name == "ball" {
                isFingerOnBall = true
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

        if isFingerOnBall {
            ball.position = touchLocation
        }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isFingerOnBall = false
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

        let radius:CGFloat = 60

        // BALL
        ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)
        ball.name = "ball"
        ball.fillColor = .red
        ball.strokeColor = .clear
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 150)
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
        ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        scene?.addChild(ball)

        // ROOM
        room = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius * 5)
        room.name = "room"
        room.strokeColor = .white
        room.lineWidth = 10
        room.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        room.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: room.path!)
        room.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        scene?.addChild(room)

    }

}
```

I expected the room's SKPhysicsBody would limit the ball go out beyond the path, 
[OK image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAV62.jpg)

but when my finger drags the ball out of the circle(room), it goes out too.
[No good image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwgbU.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few ways to do this although the simplest I can think of is to replace you didMove(to view: SKView) method with this:

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

    // BALL
    let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.fillColor = .yellow
    ball.strokeColor = .yellow
    ball.lineWidth = 5
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    addChild(ball)


    // ROOM
    let room = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 200)
    room.fillColor = .clear
    room.strokeColor = .red
    room.lineWidth = 5
    room.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: room.path!)
    room.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    room.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    room.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
    room.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    room.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    addChild(room)

}
```

Basically you just need to set the PhysicsBody CategoryBitMask and Collision Bit mask. Also don't assign a solid physics body notice the use of the "edgeFromLoop" to make the rooms physic body.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

    if isFingerOnBall {
        let roomRadius: CGFloat = 200
        let hyp = sqrt(touchLocation.x * touchLocation.x + touchLocation.y * touchLocation.y)
        if abs(hyp) > roomRadius {
            ball.position = ball.position
        } else {
            ball.position = touchLocation
        }
    }

}
```

Here you are getting the hypotenuse of the new touch point and checking to see that its greater then the radius of the room. If it is then the position of the ball remains the same, if not then update the ball position as normal.

Hope this helps and enjoy

Comment: Thanks, hoboBob!
I tried that code. Yeah, it made a collision and I felt some snag on the path, but if I drag the ball out of the circle, it's still following my finger.
I want the ball trapped in the circle even if the dragging finger is out there.

Comment: Ahhh OK I've updated the answer with a new implementation of touchesMoved for you to try

Comment: Thanks, hoboBob! That's awesome! Your solution made my code work as I wanted!